# Adobe Illustrator: How do you expand a vector to the extent of the stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke

[image]

I have some vector shapes with a white fill and a `0.3pt` white stroke.

What I want to do is expand the shape to the extent of the outside edge of the stroke.

To put it in kind of visual terms, what I'd want to see in the image above is the blue selection line on the border between the white and the pink.

I hope I've explained it well enough. If not, please ask for clarification.

Comment: This worked, although it gave me a bunch of shapes inside the one I wanted, so I'll just go through and delete them. Thanks.

Comment: 5 seconds of googling "expand + illustrator" should have solved this …

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+expand+a+shape+to+the+exten+of+the+fill&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MVmxU8aSDeLC8gfQ0oGwBQ#q=how+to+expand+a+shape+to+the+extent+of+the+stroke&rls=en

Comment: This Google search returned no useful results when I searched it before posting this question. Although, the top result in the search is now this post. But without your original comment (which I'm assuming you deleted) that containted the answer.

Comment: @timhuman if the comment you provided answered the questions, then post it as an answer with a screenshot of where the OP can find it.  OP..  If you did do a search then you should include that in your question so people will know you did try to put effort in finding out.

Comment: I should have included the Google link in my question originally, it's just that I'm more used to Stackoverflow where what people are looking for are links to class references / documentation that you've read in trying to find the answer. Will know for next time! (Upvote for Gramps for being polite and helpful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Object > Expand Appearance` then merge with `Pathfinder`.

Alternatively:

`Object > Path > Outline Stroke`

Comment: Thanks, but `Expand Appearance` is greyed out :/

Comment: then try `Expand...` first.

Comment: `Expand Appearance` is still greyed out. `Expand...` gives me the same result as tim human's method above (i.e. lot's of shapes inside the one I want), which is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 8):

A little late to the party here, but here's the way I would do it

Object > Path >Offset Path

You can adjust the size of the offset (which is basically expansion of the path) and preview it to fine tune it.

Hope this helps future users!

Comment: What is the difference between "Object" > "Path" > "Outline Stroke" from the other answer and your "Offset Path"?

Comment: @Kurt less operations and fever point artefacts

Comment: @joojaa Thanks, wouldn't it better to add that to the answer?